How to give up metadata update permission for spl token via solana api?
I have created spl token , I now want to lock the metadata so that no one can update him. I tried to do it using the following code but received the error “ ‘Program log: Error: Invalid instruction’”
splToken.createSetAuthorityInstruction(
mintPublicKey,
senderKeypair.publicKey,
splToken.AuthorityType.MetadataPointer,
null.
[], // new permission holder is null, drop casting permission
splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
)
Please help me .

The mint you provided 9KXyn1GGcefXHX5yLg1GVH4NdWAeLSXJW4oEjrmdYpY8 indicates that the Token Program owns the token, and you aren't using the Metadata pointer.
You are setting the Metadata using the Metaplex Metadata program to add the token metadata, tx here
I'll use umi in this example and set the isMutable flag to false meaning that no one can change the Metaplex Metadata.
Don't forget to update the script with the updateAuthority via the Keypair variable.
import { updateV1 } from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata";
import { publicKey } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi";
import { createUmi } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults";
import { clusterApiUrl } from "@solana/web3.js";

const umi = createUmi(clusterApiUrl("devnet"));

export const keypair = umi.eddsa.createKeypairFromSecretKey(
    Uint8Array.from([]) // update me
);

await updateV1(umi, {
    mint: publicKey("9KXyn1GGcefXHX5yLg1GVH4NdWAeLSXJW4oEjrmdYpY8"),
    authority: umi.identity,
    data: null, // if you want to change the data create an object and pass it in here
    primarySaleHappened: true,
    isMutable: false, // this will make the asset immutable
...
}).sendAndConfirm(umi);


When I modified it, I got a new error： logs: [
'Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb invoke [1]',
'Program log: Instruction: SetAuthority',
'Program log: Error: InvalidAccountData',
'Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb consumed 2223 of 200000 compute units',
'Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb failed: invalid account data for instruction'
]

What's the mint address?

Hi, the mini address is 9KXyn1GGcefXHX5yLg1GVH4NdWAeLSXJW4oEjrmdYpY8. Thank you.

@mysweet, updated my answer
